# How do I write $\Bbb Z{\left[\frac16\right]}\cap\left[\frac23,\frac43\right),+$ modulo $\frac23$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, quotient-group

> How do I talk about the elements of $\Bbb Z{\left[\frac16\right]}$ in the interval $\left[\frac23,\frac43\right)$ as a set with addition reduced by $\frac23$?

It would seem to be a torsion group with identity $\frac23$ and I imagine would most likely be thought of in the interval $\left[0,\frac23\right)$ with identity $0$, but I don't even know how to write that.

My effort would be say $\frac23+\left(\Bbb Z[\frac16]/\frac23\Bbb Z\right)$ but that's a wild stab in the dark to be fair.

What would be standard or common terminology for this, if there is any (and am I right in thinking it's a quotient group)?

Comment: Yes it is (isomorphic to) the quotient group of the additive group ${\rm Z}[1/6]$ by the cyclic subgroup $H$    generated by $2/3$. Yes it is a torsion group. It is generated by the cosets $(1/6)^k+H$, which have order $4 \times 6^{k-1}$ for $k>0$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank-you. Feel free to make that an answer.